# Two node Tomcat based Load Balancing: Architectural styles

Tags: java, tomcat, load-balancing, high-availability, failover

Am working on setting up a 2-node load balancer for Tomcat web server either using [Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html) or employing a commercial tool named [Barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/products/loadbalancer). The servers are high end Intel servers with powerful configuration (for the requirement under consideration) in terms of CPU, Memory, internal RAID. The two options we got are either to use two nodes as Active-active meaning both tomcat serving requests in a round-robin fashion or to use just one node and use the other node only in case the first node fails. One disadvantage with active-active configuration would be that the architecture won't be `Shared Nothing` type as the two tomcats potentially needs to share the web-content using a disk-array.
Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide some inputs regarding the above architectural styles.